# Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer::canTypeBeFont() must be of the type string

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2

I'm getting this error while changing stylesheet. This is the only thing that shows up on the screen. How do I begin to debug this? Reverting doesn't do anything. I've tried cache flush and setup upgrade also deleted var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/* pub/static and rebuilt. Same error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer::canTypeBeFont() must be
> of the type string, null given, called in
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
> on line 360 and defined in
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php:439
> Stack trace: #0
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(360):
> Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->canTypeBeFont(NULL) #1
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/ClientSideLessCompilation/Renderer.php(75):
> Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->addDefaultAttributes(NULL,
> ' media="print"') #2
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(422):
> Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\ClientSideLessCompilation\Renderer->addDefaultA
> in
> /chroot/home/a59125d9/domain.com/pub/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
> on line 439

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put Frontend Development Workflow back to server side less compilation

System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Frontend Development Workflow = Server Side Less Compilation

or via ssh

```
bin/magento config:set dev/front_end_development_workflow/type server_side_compilation
```

Answer (score 0):

can comment the lines around 360
vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php

```
    //if ($this->canTypeBeFont($contentType)) {
    //    return 'rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"';
    //}
```

only at the time of frontend work, then uncomment it